# How to create a dynamic table with borders in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Dynamic Table. When the user enter quantity then Value (`TextView`) should update (qty * price).
My problem is that I am creating the `TextView` & `EditText` dynamically. How to get the Id of `TextView`?

```
 EditText txtQty = new EditText(this);
        txtQty.setId(i);
        txtQty.setVisibility(1);
        txtQty.setHint("0.00");
        txtQty.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

        tr.addView(txtQty); 
        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.showSoftInput(txtQty, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))  
        .hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtQty.getWindowToken(), 0);

        txtQty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
                Log.v("TAG", "afterTextChanged" + s.toString());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                Log.v("TAG", "beforeTextChanged");
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                Log.v("TAG", "onTextChanged");
            }
        });

        TextView txtVal = new TextView(this);
        txtVal.setTextSize(1, 12);
        createView(tr, txtVal,"0.00");
```

Inside the `afterTextChanged()` method I want to set the value(`txtVal`), for example `txtVal .setText(215847.00);`

How can we call `txtVal` inside the  `afterTextChanged()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring your `txtVal` before you `addTextChangedListener()`. You probalby need to declare `txtVal` as `final TextView txtVal`. Then you should be able to set the text of `txtVal`.

Comment: Its a basic & small thing.I didn't think about this.Good.